# NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 or GTX 1660 Ti for 144Hz display laptop?

Tags: laptop, graphics-cards, displays

I'm planning to buy a laptop for work (mainly simulations/scientific computing + general use). I found the following two models: [Lenovo Legion Y540-15IRH-PG0](https://psref.lenovo.com/Detail/Legion/Lenovo_Legion_Y54015IRHPG0?M=81SY004MAD) and [Lenovo Legion Y540-15IRH](https://psref.lenovo.com/Detail/Legion/Lenovo_Legion_Y54015IRH?M=81SX005TAD). The specs are identical except for three things:

```
+---------+-------------------------+----------------------------+
| Price   | $1085                   | $1310                      | 
+---------+-------------------------+----------------------------+
| GPU     | NVidia GeForce GTX 1650 | NVidia GeForce GTX 1660 Ti |
+---------+-------------------------+----------------------------+
| Battery | 52.5 Wh                 | 57 Wh                      |
+---------+-------------------------+----------------------------+
| Charger | 170 W                   | 230 W                      |
+---------+-------------------------+----------------------------+
```

The full specification sheet is here for reference (differences highlighted in red):

[image]

[image]

The price difference, as you see, is about $225, so which one of these is better for my use and which would give better user experience in general? Will the 1650 be able to drive the 144Hz panel and provide smooth experience? or is 144Hz an overkill for it?

Comment: *Supporting* 144Hz displays and *running* programs at 144 FPS are two separate things. Both of the GPUs are capable of outputting 144 FPS to a 144Hz display, but whether the system achieves that performance without stuttering depends on the games/programs too. We can only generally tell you that the 1660 Ti is faster, and therefore "would give better user experience in general". What games or programs do you expect to run at 144 FPS?

Comment: Thanks @Romen for your reply, I don't have a specific application that is 144Hz dependent, I'm more concerned with how well these parts would play together. Will the power hungry 1660 Ti be satisfied with a small battery increase? Will it have a noticable perfromance difference in light games/GPU computing, everyday use, web browsing (smooth scrolls), watching videos? Is this 20% price increase justified? I watched reviews claiming 48% game performance increase (1660 Ti vs. 1650), but what about outside of games?

Comment: "Will the power hungry 1660 Ti be satisfied with a small battery increase?" -- The card doesn't draw more power unless you ask it to, tasks like web browsing and video playback would draw about the same power from both the 1650 and 1660 Ti (they are the same generation). While gaming, *every* laptop should be running from main A/C power because the high CPU & GPU usage would drain any battery very quickly. "Will it have a noticeable performance difference in ... everyday use, web browsing, watching videos?"  -- No, *most* GPUs can handle that, even integrated ones.